# "This work presented the computer program X" vs. "This report presented the computer program X"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, phrases

I am reading a report that presents the computer program X. The author is a student who designed and implemented this program during his M.S.

At the beginning of the last section, the author wrote "*This work presented the computer program X*". Is that turn of phrase correct? Shouldn't it be replaced by "*This report presented the computer program X*" or something similar?

Title of the report: *Program X: An end-to-end approach to unveil salient features from massive signal data sets*.

Comment: What is the **Title** of the report?  If the Title uses the word *Report,* then it can be referred to using that noun.

Comment: If I make a report, my boss may say, *"Good work!"*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Sure, title added in question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the example is correct.  It uses "work" as a noun.  The meaning is "something that is the result of creative effort."

You are also correct that using a more precise word (like "report") would probably have made the sentence better.

A "report" is a kind of "work".  Some other kinds of "works" include:

- books
- essays
- theses
- poems
- songs
- sculptures

As Floris points out, "work" has other noun definitions.  Neither of these definitions is used in the original example:

- The effort to create a work.  For example, "I have work to do."
- The physical environment and company among whom one works.  For example, "I commute to work five days per week."

Comment: "work" can mean both the effort to create the report, and the report itself. I agree with your second paragraph though.